# Sharing data with a dynamically loaded library (dlopen,dlsym)

Tags: c++

My main program would load a simple dynamic library called hello.so

***In main***

```
void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

***In main*** ,  pass a callback function called **testing (defined somewhere in main.h)** and invoke the hello() from the dynamic library

```
typedef void (*callback)();
typedef void (*hello_t)( callback);

/* do something */

hello_t hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "hello");
hello(testing);
```

***In dynamic library,***

```
#include 
#include "main.h"

extern "C" void hello( void (*fn)() ) {
  /*do something and then invoke callback function from main */  fn();
}
```

Are there other ways to allow functions/data of main to be called/used from dynamic library apart from using callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is the preferred way of doing it, in my opinion. Any other way that I can think of involves making the DLL aware of the objects in the program it's linked with, which is most likely bad practice.

Regarding data, just a reminder though you didn't ask, it's usually best practice to copy any data that needs to be stored, if it's passed across library/program boundaries. You can get into a complete mess if you have the library using data whose lifetime is controlled by the program, and vice versa.

Comment: It's because I would like to enable the use of the same logger (log4cxx) in both main and the dynamic library.

Comment: In that case, a callback is definitely a way to go.