# Python Embedded in C++

Tags: c++, python, autotools, boost-python, automake

So I have a GUI program that has a great deal of "stuff" going on. I am adding a python scripting interface so someone can interact problematically with this environment. I am using boost python. So first thing I have is a new module I want to create. For simplicity right now my module just is hello world...

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>                                                     

char const* greet() {                                                           
   return "hello, world" ;                                                      
}                                                                               

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cerrnimapi) {                                               
  boost::python::def( "greet", greet ) ;                                        
}
```

In my system I have a class that looks like this...

```
Controller::Controller( ) {         
  Py_Initialize( ) ;                                                            

  main_module = boost::python::import( "__main__" ) ;                           
  main_namespace = main_module.attr( "__dict__" ) ;                             
}                                                                                                                                                     

void Controller::execute_script( std::string filename ) {                       
  try {                                                                         
    boost::python::api::object ignored =                                        
      boost::python::exec_file( filename.c_str(), main_namespace ) ;            
  } catch( boost::python::error_already_set const & ) {                         
    if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError)) {                      
    } else {                                                                    
        PyErr_Print();                                                          
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             
}
```

Now when I go to execute the script in the GUI I get an error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mokon/repository/trunk/python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cerrnimapi
ImportError: No module named cerrnimapi
```

So of course I am building something wrong. My build system uses autotools so here are a few  pieces of that build system that relate to this...

In configure.ac:

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON                                                                  
AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_INCLUDE], [Include flags for python, bypassing python-config])
AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_CONFIG], [Path to python-config])                            
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_INCLUDE"], [                                            
  AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_CONFIG"], [                                           
    AC_PATH_PROGS([PYTHON_CONFIG],                                              
                  [python$PYTHON_VERSION-config python-config],                 
                  [no],                                                         
                  [`dirname $PYTHON`])                                          
    AS_IF([test "$PYTHON_CONFIG" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find python-config for $PYTHON.])])
  ])                                                                            
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([python include flags])                                       
  PYTHON_INCLUDE=`$PYTHON_CONFIG --includes`                                    
  AC_MSG_RESULT([$PYTHON_INCLUDE])                                              
])                                                                              

AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_LD], [Linker flags for python, bypassing python-config])     
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_LD"], [                                                 
  AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_CONFIG"], [                                           
    AC_PATH_PROGS([PYTHON_CONFIG],                                              
                  [python$PYTHON_VERSION-config python-config],                 
                  [no],                                                         
                  [`dirname $PYTHON`])                                          
    AS_IF([test "$PYTHON_CONFIG" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find python-config for $PYTHON.])])
  ])                                                                            
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([python linker flags])                                        
  PYTHON_LD=`$PYTHON_CONFIG --ldflags`                                          
  AC_MSG_RESULT([$PYTHON_LD])                                                   
])
```

In my obj/ dir Makefile.am...

```
pyexec_LTLIBRARIES = cerrnimapi.la                                              
cerrnimapi_la_SOURCES = ${SRC_DIR}/lib/PythonAPI.cpp                            
cerrnimapi_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module $(PYTHON_LD)                     
cerrnimapi_la_CXXFLAGS = $(PYTHON_INCLUDE)
```

My makefile builds the shared lib and its in the obj folder along with my main program. This doesn't help. I have also done a make install to install the cerrnimapi lib in the python folders. This doesn't help.

I have also tried adding the PythonAPI.cpp to my main programs SOURCES but to no avail.

Any ideas? let me know what additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Also the more that I think about it I think I am doing this wrong. Shouldn't I just be able to have my lib compiled into my c++ program an the embedded python interp will be able to see the symbols?

Comment: Is your build process producing a shared library named "cerrnimapi.so"? That's what the import would be looking for. As to statically linking in the library, that's not directly encouraged but there's information here if you want to hack on it: http://mdqinc.com/blog/2011/08/statically-linking-python-with-cython-generated-modules-and-packages/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Run `nm` over your .so file (which might be in `.libs`) to make sure your module init func is exported.
- Make your program print out the value of `sys.path` (use PyRun_SimpleString) to see where it's expecting your module to turn up. If you're defining modules for your interpreter only, you probably don't want to install them in `$pyexecdir`.
- Read the [Extending Embedded Python](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python) article. You don't really need to build dynamic libraries at all, unless you're trying for a plugin architecture.

A point on style: You should try and find `$PYTHON_CONFIG` outside of your tests for `$PYTHON_INCLUDE` and `$PYTHON_LD` so you're not doing the `AC_PATH_PROGS` twice:

```
AM_PATH_PYTHON                                                                  
AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_CONFIG], [Path to python-config])                            
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_CONFIG"], [                                           
  AC_PATH_PROGS([PYTHON_CONFIG],                                              
                [python$PYTHON_VERSION-config python-config],                 
                [no],                                                         
                [`dirname $PYTHON`])                                          
])                                                                            

AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_INCLUDE], [Include flags for python, bypassing python-config])
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_INCLUDE"], [                                            
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([python include flags])                                       
  AS_IF([test "$PYTHON_CONFIG" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find python-config for $PYTHON.])])
  PYTHON_INCLUDE=`$PYTHON_CONFIG --includes`                                    
  AC_MSG_RESULT([$PYTHON_INCLUDE])                                              
])                                                                              

AC_ARG_VAR([PYTHON_LD], [Linker flags for python, bypassing python-config])     
AS_IF([test -z "$PYTHON_LD"], [                                                 
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([python linker flags])                                        
  AS_IF([test "$PYTHON_CONFIG" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find python-config for $PYTHON.])])
  PYTHON_LD=`$PYTHON_CONFIG --ldflags`                                          
  AC_MSG_RESULT([$PYTHON_LD])                                                   
])
```

Comment: So the python api I am creating needs access to the model back in my  main app since it needs to interact with it. For instance I have a simple command that shuts down that system. To do that it grabs a global object and essentially calls its shutdown method. The problem of course is that is calling that from the .so dynamically linked file and thus that global is null. I need it to access from the main program. I didn't see where in that article you were referring too

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. I feel this is something really basic... Its been a while since I've had to worry about this...

Comment: The section of the manual I linked to you shows how to define a module inside your main program. You don't need to have a .so at all. To call back into your main program, it looks like you have to pass function pointers around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454909/sharing-data-with-a-dynamically-loaded-library-dlopen-dlsym . Don't do that, it gets messy.

Comment: Ok, yeah it seems boost isn't doing everything in that example. The program works fine if I do it like in that example but I am doing it with boost..
e.g. "import emb 
print "Number of arguments", emb.numargs()"

And this causes some errors

Comment: Get rid of the dynamic linking. You don't need to make and load plugins to expose your own program's API. Just link your PythonAPI.cpp into your main program.

Comment: Yeah doing that. 100% agree. This works when I do it like that example. It doesnt work with boost. Is boost only meant for dynamic linking?

Comment: I think I found the answer here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython -> "Now, inside `main()` and before the call to `Py_Initialize()` we want to call `PyImport_AppendInittab( "CppMod", &initCppMod );` `initCppMod` is a function created by the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro which is used to initialize the Python module `CppMod`. At this point, your embedded python script may call `import CppMod` and then access CppClass as a member of the module.